# yii2 проблемы с установкой

Tags: php, yii2

Установил Composer, обновил его, установил yii2, перехожу в браузер для проверки,а вместо "приветствия" выдает следующие ошибки :

Warning: require(C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\web/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\web\index.php on line 7

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\web/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.6;c:/openserver/modules/php/PHP-5.6/PEAR/pear') in C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\web\index.php on line 7

уже и OpenServer до последней версии установил, и Googla я наверное достал)) подскажите, благодарен любому совету

Comment: установку `yii2` как сделали? вручную скачали с оф. сайта да?

Comment: в консоле прописал composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic какое-то назв 2.0.12

Comment: и да, с оф.сайта все

Comment: Так попробуй установить
composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic

Comment: спасибо) все вышло) а можете объяснить почем та команда не давала нужного результата ? ведь оф.документация и т.д

Comment: вы скачали наверное не стабильную версию, и там в ՝vendor՝ не все зависимости были

Comment: понял, спасибо еще раз

Comment: вы инициализировали проект?